# Android Kitkat resources bug "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException"

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on android app and it is working good on all android versions >= lolipop and gives fatal error on kitkat and below. 
This is the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.tequeen.mallakydriver/com.tequeen.mallakydriver.SplashActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004b

and it points to this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);` but the `activity_splash.xml` is already there and I am sure on that.

any advice, thanks.

Edit: the build.gradle content

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tequeen.mallakydriver"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Manifest content:

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Splash Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Custom theme:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: May be it's a problem with style. Check that whether your activity extends Activity class or AppCompatActivity.

Comment: `public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity` it extends AppCompatActivity as you can see

Comment: Also check minimum SDK support in your gradle file

Comment: @KushPatel I edited my question with gradle content, please check it  and thanks for your help

Comment: is the layout in the `res.layout` folder? do you have any other layouts with the same name ?

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov Yes it is there and the app working fine on higher android versions

Comment: @MohammedTawfik what Theme are you using?

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov I am using custom theme "SplashTheme" and it is defined on styles.xml file

Comment: `<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>`

Comment: @MohammedTawfik post more code in the question, including the theme form the `styles.xml` and the part in the manifest where you use that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131255/discussion-between-mohammed-tawfik-and-ognian-gloushkov).

Comment: Are you using a vector drawable in your layout? If the answer is yes, just add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in the defaultConfig section of your build.gradle

Comment: will you show your activity_splash.xml because setContentView error not only includes the error of the invisibility but also it can be an error in the xml it self